# Fragment's on CreateView is not called when using ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, fragment-oncreateview

I'm developing an Android Application where I have a ViewPager in my MainActivity, consisting of 3 Fragments.
The Problem is as follows, when I swipe to the 3rd fragment, and get back to the 1st one, onCreateView of fragment 1 is called which is what I really want, however, If I swipped to the 2nd fragment only, and returned to the 1st one, onCreateView is not called!
I need to find a solution to this problem, I spent hours trying to find a solution but didn't know to solve it.
Here's the code related to the ViewPager in my MainActivity

```
    private void setupViewPager(final ViewPager viewPager) {
    final ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFrag(new voting(), "ONE");
    adapter.addFrag(new dashboard(), "TWO");
    adapter.addFrag(new chats(), "THREE");
    myAdapter=adapter;
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);
}

private class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<String>();

    private ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Log.i("getItem","getItem");
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    private void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    //added newly
    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object){
        return PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: "If I swipped to the 2nd fragment only, and returned to the 1st one, onCreateView is not called" -- if you mean that `onCreateView()` is not called again on the first fragment, that is perfectly normal. "I need to find a solution to this problem" -- why do you think that it is a problem?

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes this is what I mean, but did not find a solution yet

Answer (score 2):

This is intended behavior with a [`FragmentPagerAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html). If the fragment was already created and is still in memory, it is just reattached to the ViewPager. Hence, the reason why `onCreateView(...)` isn't called a second time.

> Implementation of PagerAdapter that represents each page as a Fragment that is persistently kept in the fragment manager as long as the user can return to the page.

You're using a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` which is a subclass of `FragmentPagerAdapter`, so it inherits this behavior.

Generally, it's not a good idea to recreate a view on every page change, as that is expensive and can lead to non smooth scrolling. If you had some logic in `onCreateView(...)` that you want to run again on each fragment change, then I suggest looking into [`ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html) interface.

Comment: what if my logic is somehow related to the inflater in onCreateView and ViewGroup and that stuff? how can i execute this logic from the mainActivity?

Comment: Use the inflater to create views, and hold references to those views in the fragment to interact with them later. You shouldn't need an inflater after `onCreateView(...)` unless you're dynamically creating views for some reason.

Update your question with your inflater use case and maybe we can suggest a better pattern :)